# From Cologne to Maastricht departing at 23h15, is that possible by public transportation?

Tags: public-transport, night-transport, cologne, maastricht

I am flying to Cologne late and need to get to Maastricht. Are there any public transports that make that possible at 23h15?

Comment: Try [bahn.de](http://bahn.de). But I found at 03:27.

Answer (score 1):

Going from Cologne (Koln) to Maastricht is possible at 3 AM. Please check this site for the options: http://www.nshispeed.nl/en

This is the train site for international transport From any country to Holland.