# Which is the cheapest way of travelling between Cologne and Maastricht by public transport?

Tags: public-transport, price, cologne, maastricht

I am looking for the cheapest way to travel between cologne and Maastricht.

There are so many options/special tickets, that I allways feel there is probably something I am missing. It's an art to master all these options.

In the Euregio there is the Euregio Ticket that allows unlimited travel in the eueregio region for one day. In Germany there is the SchönerTagTicket Nordrhein-Westfalen.  If you buy tickets in advance in german train you also get a discount...

Does any one know what's the best option? am I forgettting some obscure option that makes life cheaper and easier?

What's the way of travelling the cheapest, by public transport, between Cologne and Maastricht?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your other [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/29108/from-cologne-to-maastricht-departing-at-23h15-is-that-possible-by-public-transp), I guess you want to travel from Köln Airport to Maastricht station.

Taking the train from Köln Airport to Aachen will cost you €16,80 ([bahn.de](http://www.bahn.de)), and then from Aachen you can take the bus 50 to Maastricht for €5,50 ([Veolia Limburg](https://www.veolia-transport.nl/limburg/kaarten-en-tarieven/buskaarten/dagkaarten-z-limburg/index.html)). Bus 50 leaves just outside the station, timetables can be found on [9292](http://www.9292.nl).

A cheaper option might be a ride-share ("Mitfahrgelegenheit"), depending on availability of someone driving this exact route on the day you want. Two sites offering ride-share are [here](http://www.mitfahrzentrale.de/) and [here](http://www.mitfahrgelegenheit.de/). When I checked, offers were around €8, however, this will not include the ticket from Köln Airport to where the agreed meeting point will be.